# How can I log in to my working Google internet account with Apple Mail on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, authentication

I want Apple Mail to talk to a gmail account. In System Preferences, when I say I want a new Google account, I get a dialog that says

> Google requires completing authentication in your web browser

So I click the button and immediately I see another dialog

> Failed to authenticate with Google, please try again later

There is no evident communication with the browser, so I can't authenticate. I've also tried creating a normal manual mail account, but no better luck.

I have turned on Less Secure App Access for the account I want to use. I have no difficult logging into this account using the web (gmail.com), but I don't want to handle my mail that way; I need it to be part of my mail.

This has worked fine on other machines. This one is Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: The authentication screen should open in Safari.

Comment: @IconDaemon And the question is why it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried with Safari already open? Is Safari set to be your default browser?

Comment: @IconDaemon Those are great questions but I went thru all of that. The problem is now solved (see answer) but I still do not know why.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is likely not going to be useful, but the problem just mysteriously fixed itself. In Internet Accounts pref pane, I created a new account with Add Other Account (not Google), entered the information, and the account sprang to life successfully. I have no idea why.

All of this has something to do, I'm pretty sure, with the new use of OAuth by Google. Maybe it sometimes just doesn't work at the server end. I came into the process this time armed with the concept "OAuth" in my head, but unless the computer (or Google) was reading my mind, it was never actually used during setup.

It is interesting that, peeking into Keychain Access, on my Big Sur machine, my google accounts have OAuth entries, but my Catalina keychain has no such entries. This makes me think that Catalina just doesn't really understand OAuth, even when updated to the latest version.

Comment: This is good advice. I've had Apple tell me my password was wrong when clearly it was an issue on their authentication servers. it's hard to get the correct error message out to everyone for reasons. Add to that different software versions, implementations, bug fixes - breakage can be inscrutable and waiting is sometimes a very good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the same issue by restarting the computer in safe mode and then adding the account as a Google account in the Internet Accounts prefpane. It opened the browser window and allowed me to authenticate.

Now that I've restarted out of safe mode the account is still working, and adding new accounts appears to be working again too. I have no idea why though!

Comment: I had the same issue in my Mac with BigSur. And it got fixed after following this answer of starting the computer in safe mode and adding Google account as an internet account. Thanks @caitlin

Answer (score -2):

Check if system time is correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).